# Why do some API providers require an API key?

Tags: web-services, api

Several web service APIs have you sign up for an API key. For example, UPS Web services requires a key, which is included in calls to their service -- *In addition to the username and password*.

What is this key used for by the provider? Perhaps UPS is the only one to require both API key and username/password?

One idea is that they use it to limit or measure API usage, but it seems to me that a setting in the users profile could easily do the same thing -- especially since you generally have to get an account w/ username and password to get the API in the first place.

Comment: Why did you make this a wiki?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two predominant use cases. The first is to measure, track and restrict API usage. If someone is building a service that allows third parties to access it, the service provider may want to control (or at least know) who has access so that they can try and prevent things like denial of service attacks. On the measure and track side, interesting information can be obtained such as knowing which applications are popular for accessing the service or which features people use the most.

The other use case is related to security and authentication. It is unwise for a service provider to have third party applications and services require users to give up their username and password for the primary service. This is a huge exposure. That is why many services are standardizing on protocols such as [OAuth](http://oauth.net), which provides delegated access via authorization to a user's data. While not foolproof, it is definitely preferable to distributing user credentials to unknown, and untrusted, parties.

Comment: When it comes to restriction of API usage, isnt it possible to use the API Key of, say, a 3rd party "Application A" and mock it in through another "Application B" and get the request served? How is the security purpose served here in this case?

Answer (score 4):

Most of the time it is to monitor how developers are using the web-api. If they somehow disagree with your usage of the api it provides a means for them to shut it/you down without hurting the other users. And the statistics per user/app are always valuable.

I've used the flickr api - in that situation the key is yours, but the login data might be those of people using your app, so the api key is the only way to differentiate between the apps.

Comment: yep - now I remember - same thing with gracenote

Answer (score 1):

Usually it used to get stats on how much application performing queries to API. 
I think asking username/password with API key is ambigious in some cases, but it is a way how it is implemented - so we can't do something with it.

They ask for API key because you could have more than one API under same account - in case you have more than one site which are use same API.

Answer (score 0):

They could use it to signify which version of the API you are trying to use.  Perhaps in Version 1.0, there is a method that takes a POST on www.UPS.com/search and there is another one in version 2.0 at the same address, but takes a different parameter set, or even returns data in a different format/style.  Your program was built on V1.0 and expects a certain API contract.  They want to be able to create V2.0 without interfering with their customer's products.

That's just a guess, but it sounds good to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think Gracenote does a similar thing for cddb.  I forget the details, but I remember something about some token.

(They have/had really draconian rules about using their service too.)

Simon reminded me what the gracenote thing was.  Gracenote and Fedex and other webservices have lots of developers writing apps for the software.  So the developers get a token to put into their apps, but the end users have their own user name and password.  It lets the services keep an eye on abusing programs, etc.  That is probably te primary reason.  (like a browser or a webbot informing the webserver who/what it is)

Answer (score 0):

Originally, Blogger required you to apply for an API key (a la Google Maps) and used it to restrict access to the API. As Blogger evolved into Metaweblog, the requirement for the API became less important, and Blogger no longer requires you to apply for a key. As noted by others, it can still be used for tracking purposes.

Answer (score 0):

In our situation, our clients want it for:

- Tracking/analytics - figuring out who's doing what and building what products. Because a number of users are desktop apps, just looking at referrers isn't always enough.
- Permissions - which resources should a user have access to? How can a user build apps that have access to specified resources?
- Licensing/legal - enforcing that users have read and accepted ToU/licensing information.
- Security - passing around usernames/passwords is a really bad idea.